# Question deletion and no change in reputation

Tags: discussion

When a question with some upvotes or downvotes but no answer is deleted by the person who posted, the reputation of that person does not change. Why is that?

**EDIT:** I figured out the answer to a question I asked, and therefore, deleted the question (with no answers) but overall 3 upvotes. I do not remember whether it had any downvotes. But there is no change in my reputation.

Comment: It would change. The amount of rep gained by upvotes must have been equal to the loss of rep from downvotes.

Comment: Please give example(s) otherwise it's unclear what you mean.

Comment: Example is given.

Comment: How old was the question? As a side note - if you found the answer, why not self-answer? Somebody else might be looking for the answer that you found.

Comment: Is it appropriate to answer your own question?

Comment: @SRS Yes! It is [explicitly encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in the Help Center.

Comment: No need to answer, it's already answered in an older question.